# Kafka Streams - Volumes to state stores causes "Failed to delete the state directory" errors

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Short overview:

I have a service written in `scala` using `kafka-streams` running inside a dedicated `docker`.
To allow `state-stores` dirs to be stored where i want, i created a `volume` from the state stores dir inside the container to some dir outside. Once i did that, started seeing such exceptions in the container logs:

```
 Failed to delete the state directory.
 java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /usr/src/app/stateStores/MyServiceStreams___20/0_0
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:242)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
        at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:763)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils$2.postVisitDirectory(Utils.java:746)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)
        at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.delete(Utils.java:746)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:290)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateDirectory.cleanRemovedTasks(StateDirectory.java:253)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams$2.run(KafkaStreams.java:795)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems it doesn't effect any functionality, just spams the logs.

Analysing the logs it show the following line before the error message:

`Deleting obsolete state directory 0_0 for task 0_0 as 79998936ms has elapsed (cleanup delay is 6000000ms`

Increasing the `state.cleanup.delay.ms` param didn't help.

[Edit]
Some technicals:

1. The `/usr/src/app/stateStores/` are with `root` permissions
2. from inside the container, can remove the dirs (running as `root`). From outside, no (not `root`..)
3. `kafka-streams` version: `2.1.0`

Please assist

Comment: What's the version of Kafka Streams? How do you stop the app? What's the permissions of `/usr/src/app/stateStores/MyServiceStreams___20` directory? Can it be removed as a docker user?

Comment: Maybe related to know issues: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6647?jql=project%20%3D%20KAFKA%20AND%20text%20~%20"DirectoryNotEmptyException"

Comment: @JacekLaskowski - edited the question to include the answers to your questions. Thanks for the help